# Activity layout not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to call a second activity from my Main Activity, using this code

```
Intent goToOrder = new Intent(ListOfOrdersActivity.this, OrderSummaryActivity.class);
startActivity(goToOrder);
```

Being my OrderSummaryActivity:

```
public class OrderSummaryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order_summary);
    }
}
```

But the layout wont show on this activity, just a blank page.
This is the xml of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_resume_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quantity"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_resume_quantity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/whipped_cream"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_resume_whipped_cream"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chocolate"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_resume_chocolate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/order_summary_total"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_resume_total"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any hint?

Comment: There must be another onCreate method. Use that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing your **OrderSummaryActivity.class** to :

```
    public class OrderSummaryActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.order_summary);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

try overriding

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

instead of

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```