# Can't make an activity actually launch

Tags: java, android

My app only shows a white screen and I believe this is due to the main activity launch thing, but I'm a newbie and can't really see what I'm missing.

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="meudominio.com.agenda">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Agenda">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity:

```
package domain.com.agenda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        TextView sample = new TextView(this);
        sample.setText("hello world");
        setContentView(sample);

    }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've overridden the wrong `onCreate()` method. You want the one without the `PersistableBundle` parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37367101.

Comment: This is it, thank you!