# GridView shows up as black/white background but without any information

Tags: android-studio, gridview

I have this kind of problem
[this is GridView when i try to open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byz0E.png)

It just shows up as black. Tested it in empty new project, In new project it was working great without any problem.
In my project i am working with google map sdk, firebase for users and gridview for photo album.
I want to show you now my Manifest, implementations and the code.

My manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.buchqiversion2" >
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BuchqiVersion2" >

        <activity
            android:name=".FullView"
            android:theme="@style/fullViewTheme">
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".GridView"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PhoneLoginActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

my GridView code

```
    android.widget.GridView gridView;
    ActivityGridviewBinding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        
        binding = ActivityGridviewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        
        Toast.makeText(this,"grid started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String[] items = {"Mishka's Room"};
        
        int[] images = {R.drawable.login_background};
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,items,images);
        
        binding.myGridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

ImageAdapter

```
    private Context mContext;
    String[] items;
    int[] image;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] items, int[] image) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (layoutInflater == null){
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,null);
        }

        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

        imageView.setImageResource(image[position]);
        textView.setText(items[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Implementations

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'




    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.buchqiversion2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }



    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Glide//
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    //Material Design//
    implementation'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

    //Animato Dependency//
    implementation 'com.github.mohammadatif:Animatoo:master'

    //Country Code//
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.1'

    //Retrofit Dependency//
    implementation'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    //Pin View//
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.4'
    //Pin View//
```

Comment: Even when i try to open up as MAIN it still wont work

Comment: You've overridden the wrong `onCreate()` method in the `Activity`. You want the one _without_ the `PersistableBundle` parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37367101. Btw, questions like this should be tagged [android] instead of [android-studio], since it's not really about the IDE.

Comment: Wow man thanks A LOT.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer